# How to keep chairs from moving across the floor?

Tags: furniture

These chairs shown in the product link are pretty much unusable on Wood and Tile floors as they keep moving around at the slightest motion by the kids.

http://www.costco.com/.product.100227337.html

I have been looking for rubber bushes that fit the chairs/tables but could not find the right sized ones. Is there some easy, hacky way (but not totally weird looking), to make some kind of DIY bushes for the legs? If so what material and where to get it?

The chair legs are steel with some kind of powder coating, there is a small hard plastic bush on the legs, but that does not help and it glides over anything other than carpet.

Don't want to put a mat under the chairs because the kids eat their food on this set and its quite difficult to cleanup the mat each time.

Also open to any other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut up a heavy bicycle inner tube glue it.

Shave the fuzz off a tennis ball and slit it.

Slit a racquetball might work

Google rubber boot for chair rectangular

Answer (score 3):

Buy duct tape that is the same color as the chair legs, and cut a small piece to put over each "foot" of each chair. This ought to increase friction with the floor and keep the chairs from sliding so easily.

Note that the duct tape would need to be reapplied periodically, as the pieces you add will probably slide a bit due to use.

(If it turns out that this solution isn't permanent enough, just peel off the duct tape and remove and residual adhesive from the chair feet using an inexpensive adhesive remover.)